# -daystart in OS X?

Tags: macos, bash, osx-snow-leopard

I'm currently running Snow Leopard and I've hit a snag in my bash script. Part of it is using the 'find' command but apparently the '-daystart' flag is not supported in OS X.

Does anyone know of a workaround or an alternative?

Comment: A description of the flag from a gnu man page: `Measure times (for -amin, -atime, -cmin, -ctime, -mmin, and -mtime) from the beginning of today rather than from 24 hours ago. This option only affects tests which appear later on the command line.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-daystart` is a GNU extension not supported by BSD find. Hopefully, you can install the GNU version as well.

I'd suggest you install [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) or [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/). You can then install GNU find with `brew install findutils` or `port install findutils`.

It will add `gfind`, which supports `-daystart`.